# ImageButton Won't Change 'background' When Pressed and Released

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm making an app that has buttons and when a button is clicked, it will play a sound. My problem is that I couldn't find a way to change mSoundButton's background when pressed and released. I'm using 'background' instead of 'src' so I can shrink the button without cutting from edges. I haven't added sounds yet because I want to solve this issue before starting to add sounds.

Here is my codes for the button in MainActivity.java (It works okay, but not in the way I wanted. It changes background when pressed but not released.)

```
        final ImageButton mSoundBtn;
        final boolean[] soundBtnClicked = {false};
        mSoundBtn = findViewById(R.id.soundButton);
        mSoundBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(soundBtnClicked[0])
                    mSoundBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_clicked);
                else
                    mSoundBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_not_clicked);

                soundBtnClicked[0] = !soundBtnClicked[0];
            }
        });
```

and here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/soundButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_not_clicked"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE (PROBLEM SOLVED):

I wanted the mSoundBtn to change image when pressed, then change image again when it is released. I used the `Handler` class and the `postDelayed()` method to create a delay between two image changes. It doesn't actually wait for user to release the button but still solved my issue. Following is the solution I found:

```
public ImageButton mSoundBtn;
Handler h = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSoundBtn = findViewById(R.id.soundButton);
    mSoundBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_clicked);
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mSoundBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_not_clicked);
                }
            }, 1000); // 1 Second
        }
    });
```

What happens is when the mSoundBtn is clicked, It changes image and waits for 1000 milliseconds (1 second), then changes back to previous image which creates some kind of animation when it is pressed so the user can understand when the button is pressed.

Thanks for anyone who have tried to help, thanks for reading. :)

Comment: Bro i recommend you use the background state list like @Geeky bean below. It's simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define it as 'final'
Sample:

```
    public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variables
    public ImageButton mSoundBtn;
    public boolean isSoundBtnSelected = false; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        mSoundBtn = findViewById(R.id.soundButton);
        mSoundBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isSoundBtnSelected)
                    mSoundBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_clicked);
                else
                    mSoundBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_not_clicked);

                isSoundBtnSelected = !isSoundBtnSelected;
            }
        });
      }

    }
```

Comment: I can not start with public. It says "illegal start of expression". When I delete public I cannot access to the variable from inner class and it tells me to add final.

Comment: Sorry for answering late. Your code has solved the issue about access from inner class, but button needs to be clicked twice in order to get it to it's first image. I want it to change to it's image at the beginning when released. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want an action to be done after the user removed the finger from the button (meaning the press is done).
Try using OnTouchListener instead of OnClickListener:

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            // change background and other stuff...
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you only wanted to change the button's background when it pressed, you can use a selector drawable for that, like so:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_activated="true"
    android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" /> <!-- default -->
```

and just place it as the button's background.

Another option is to use a toggle button and OnChecked listener and change the background when the user checks (press) the button. If you want the background to be permanently changed after the first toggle you can implement this by changing the background only after the first toggle.

Comment: Yeah that is what I want the button to do basically but I also need button to do when it is pressed. I'm trying it now. It will probably solve the issue.